# What is Card Board's filterBoard() function?

Tags: javascript, rally

It seems that the card board has an undocumented filterBoard() function. I have no idea what it exactly does, other than nomenclature, or what parameter it takes. Has anyone come across this/used this function before, and could provide some enlightenment?

This is the javascript that was returned when I simply ran "cardBoard.filterBoard":

```
function (_c11) {
    _b85.filterBy = _c11;
    if (_c11 && _c11.field !== undefined && _c11.value !== undefined) {
        rally.forEach(_b7f, function (_c12) {
            rally.forEach(_c12.getDndSource().getItems(), function (item) {
                var node = _c12.getDndSource().getNode(item.ObjectID);
                if (node) {
                    var _c13 = that.getCardRenderer(_c12, item);
                    if (dojo.isFunction(_c13.updateCard)) {
                        _c13.updateCard(node);
                    } else {
                        _c12.getDndSource().refreshItem(item, item);
                    }
                }
            });
        });
    }
    if (dojo.query(".filterByShow").length === 0 && _c11 && _c11.value) {
        _b9f("The selected value, " + _c11.value + ", is not assigned to " + _c11.field + " for any of the displayed cards.");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you include ?debug=true in your sdk.js script include you can get the uncompressed version of the code to make it easier to read...

That method was added in order to support filtering the board (causing certain cards to fade out and others to be more prominent based on some criteria).  It is used by the Kanban Board in conjunction with the tag dropdown.

If you're looking to actually change the data on the board (re-query the server) you should call the refresh() method with an updated query in the passed config.

Comment: I see. Do you happen to know what the criteria would need to be? Or is it user-defined?

Also, in terms of the refresh() function, would it be any different, in terms of a visual UI perspective, if a new cardboard were created when the query changed, rather than calling this to re-query? Well, other than referential integrity when creating a new Card Board and perhaps slight, if any, overheard for creating a new object.

Comment: filterBoard is used like this in the Kanban app:
    cardboard.filterBoard({field: 'Tags.Name', value: dropdown.getDisplayedValue()});


refresh will leave the columns in place and just reload the data.  otherwise you can do a destroy and then create a new one and redisplay it.  usually the second is about as fast as the first and you don't even notice a blink.